# jquery highlight table column by header value

Tags: jquery

How can I highlight a table column based on `<th>Mar</th>` value? If the head contains for example `Mar` then highlight the whole column with the header?

```js
var target = $("table th:contains('Mar')").css("background-color", "#FF0000");

$('table tr td:nth-child(' + (target.index() + 1) + ')').css("background-color", "#FF0000");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried yourself?

Comment: I think I found a solution. You can check the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var index = $('th:contains("Mar")').eq(0).index();
 $("tr").each(function(rowIndex, row){
    $(row).find("th:eq(" + index + ")").css('background', 'green');
    $(row).find("td:eq(" + index + ")").css('background', 'green');
 });
});
</script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer because is more elegant than mine :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can use a column group to mark your columns, like this:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
....
</table>
```

and then, after you find the index of the column you want by querying the `<th>` elements, style the matching `<col>` element. this is more efficient than going over all the rows of the table.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if anyone downvoting me will comment why he did so.